# MVC 5 Razor System.Security.SecurityException

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Just created a new application and put the trust level Medium in web.config

```
<trust level="Medium" />
```

I need to test the application in Medium trust level because I have to host on shared server.

Now run the application and get error on this line

```
@Html.ActionLink("XYZ", "Index", "Home", new {area=""}, new {@class="link" })
```

Here is the complete error:

Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Source Error:

```
                 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
             @Html.ActionLink("xyz", "Index", "Home", 
             new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
         </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```

Stack Trace:

```
[SecurityException: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.]
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(Object demand, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean isPermSet) +0
   System.Security.CodeAccessSecurityEngine.Check(CodeAccessPermission cap, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +34
   System.Security.CodeAccessPermission.Demand() +46
   System.Web.HttpContext.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type service) +54
   System.Web.HttpContextWrapper.GetService(Type serviceType) +13
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.IsUrlRewriterTurnedOn(HttpContextBase httpContext) +157
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlRewriterHelper.WasRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext) +37
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +229
   System.Web.WebPages.UrlUtil.GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath) +120
   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues) +324
   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, String protocol, String hostName, String fragment, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RouteCollection routeCollection, RequestContext requestContext, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GenerateLinkInternal(RequestContext requestContext, RouteCollection routeCollection, String linkText, String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, String protocol, String hostName, String fragment, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes, Boolean includeImplicitMvcValues) +96
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(RequestContext requestContext, RouteCollection routeCollection, String linkText, String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, String protocol, String hostName, String fragment, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +71
   System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.GenerateLink(RequestContext requestContext, RouteCollection routeCollection, String linkText, String routeName, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +66
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String linkText, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +187
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String linkText, String actionName, String controllerName, Object routeValues, Object htmlAttributes) +115
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() in d:\TestProjects\Medium\Medium\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml:19
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +270
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +121
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +145
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer) +41
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass3.<RenderPageCore>b__2(TextWriter writer) +335
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +42
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer, HelperResult content) +45
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +53
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +178
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +229
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +154
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +695
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +431
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +529
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +321
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +37
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9742689
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago. My problem with the trust medium level was that my cshtml had a "~" at the javascript tag, like:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/foo.js"></script>
```

Removing the "~" simply resolved my problem.

It's a weird error because it points to a Razor declaration instead of the "~" line. Although the "~" is a special Razor symbol in this case.

Hope this might help.